# Hibernate @DiscriminatorValue not picked up

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Table("changes")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
class Change {
  @Column(name="type", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
  @GeneratedValue
  String _type;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  User _user;
}

@Entity
class EmailChange extends Change {}

@Entity
class BillingChange extends Change {}

@Entity
class User {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "_user", cascade = Array(Cascade.ALL))
  List<EmailChange> _emailChanges;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "_user", cascade = Array(Cascade.ALL))
  List<BillingChange> _billingChanges;
}
```

I would expect _emailChanges to contain only rows where type = "EmailChange", and _billingChanges rows with type = "BillingChange".  However this is not what actually happens - both end up containing rows of both types.  Is there any way to force it to obey the polymorphic relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You mapped it as SINGLE_TABLE, so all columns are going to a single table. OneToMany creates a foreign key to that table. The same table can't have different columns.

Comment: The table has exactly the same columns.  However, I would expect this foreign key to still obey the type of the requested object, that is to restrict on type="emailChange" or type="billingChange", and this doesn't seem to happen.